# supervised keyphrase extraction weka or other tool

Tags: weka, supervised-learning

How to use WEKA to find keyphrases with supervised méthod.

i have to learn model for keyphrase extraction, so i have a corpus for training (for every document a correspending file that contain keyphrases or keywords)

Also i have a corpus for test the supervised model (docuement without keyphrases file), so the model should output a list of keyphrases for every document.

My question is how to input the document into weka, should i add for every document

@attribute doc string

@data
"Docu1............"
"Docu2............"
...
..
"DocuN............"

Now how to input the files that contain th keyphrases for every document to learn from the model?

Answer (score 1):

First you need choose what features want to use: the most basic algorithm only based on the tf-idf values. 
https://code.google.com/p/kea-algorithm/
But you can extends this features your "task-specific" feautres too. 
For example the first occurance of the phrase etc. You can find some possible features in this article: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/S/S10/S10-1040.pdf
Than, you have to choose a machine learning algorithm and train it you train data set, and evaluate it on your test set.

Comment: This question is similar to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002095/how-to-use-weka-in-keyphrase-extraction-from-text-arguments

Comment: Thank what i understand is that after the traning of the model with a machine learning algorithm , the system will be able de detect keyphrases automatically and return a list of kyphrases, have you any idea about the best algorithm to test

Comment: You can try maximum entropy or regression based classifiers or baysian.